# Classificação Semântica para Categorização de Produtos: Estratégias e Recomendações?

Tags: python, classificação, machine-learning, ciência-de-dados, aprendizagem-de-máquina

Olá, colegas, estou buscando orientação e ficaria extremamente grato por qualquer ajuda que possam oferecer.

Para contextualizar: estou trabalhando em um sistema cujo objetivo principal é categorizar produtos vendidos em supermercados. Atualmente, recebo somente o código de barras e a descrição do produto. Com base nesses dados, preciso determinar a qual categoria o produto pertence. Eis um exemplo:

Entrada:

```
{
"Código": "7896035700021",
"Descrição": "CAPSULA MELITTA INTENS.9 MARCATO C/10"
}
```

Saída:

```
{
"Código": "7896035700021",
"Descrição": "CAPSULA MELITTA INTENS.9 MARCATO C/10",
"Categoria": "Café Em Cápsulas"
}
```

O desafio é que a categorização é feita manualmente, tornando-se uma tarefa árdua. Até o momento, já categorizei aproximadamente 2 milhões de itens. Estes estão distribuídos em 520 categorias distintas.

Meu plano é desenvolver um modelo de classificação semântica. Pretendo representar as descrições dos produtos como vetores. Assim, para cada novo produto, converteria sua descrição em um vetor e determinaria sua categoria usando similaridade de cosseno, comparando-o com os produtos já categorizados.

Dada esta abordagem, gostaria de saber: É uma boa estratégia para esse tipo de desafio? Existem métodos mais eficientes ou recomendados para essa situação? Como sou relativamente novo na área de Ciência de Dados, agradeço qualquer insight ou recomendação que possam oferecer.

Desde já, muito obrigado.

Comment: As "categorias" devem vir das necessidades das áreas que vão usar as informações para tomar decisões, o Sistema que faz a operação do Supermercado já deve ter estas informações pois precisa pagar impostos, distribuir as mercadorias pelas lojas , fazer pedidos etc. Eu iniciaria pelo que já existe e só faria outra "categorização" se fosse necessátio. Não sei se ajudei.

Comment: Talvez também seja preciso uma hierarquia, alimentícios>>chás.cafés.etc>>cafés>>café capsula.

Comment: Mas isto está fora do escopo deste site, talvez seja assunto para alguma comunidade de ciência de dados.